# APK file cannot be open

Tags: android-studio, apk

I want to download an apk file from android studio. The build was successful and the installation was successful. However I am not able to open the app. Is there a way I can open the app?

For confidential sake I am not able to share the codes

Comment: Since your installation was successful I guess it is safe to assume that you enabled developer mode on your phone.
Your wanted to run the app using the play button (run app, shift+ f10) and the expected result would have been that after a successful build the app starts on your phone but instead it is not?
I have that same issue sometimes and pressing the "Run 'app'" button again usually works for me (which is still not satisfactory for me -> I would rather want the app to start the first time)

Comment: Im actually using a mobile device instead of the virtual device. After the app finish installing, there will be two options, done and open. However I can only press the done button

Comment: I have connected an actual device via USB as well. However, I have never seen an alert dialog like this. I guess that the output of the "Run" console window would be helpful. It should be something like:
Launching 'app' on [mobile device name]
followed by and adb command and in the success case a message like "Connected to process [PROCESS_ID] on device [nobile device name]"

Comment: i dont have enough memory to download a virtual device hence im downloading it to my device using the apk